# Import Excel files into Access whilst Looping

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am comfortable with using VBA to import excel sheets into access, and to loop through a given folder to bring back everything in there.  However, I want to loop through a folder and only import a selection of the files.  Can someone help?  Each file is called `REPORT1` etc and runs to `REPORT67`.  I only want to pick `1-47`.

Code below works fine, but this just copies everything in from the specified location.

```
Sub Sample2()
Const cstrFolder As String = "F:\TCB_HR_KPI\Data View\"
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Long

strFile = Dir(cstrFolder & "*.xls")
If Len(strFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Files Found"
Else
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Debug.Print cstrFolder & strFile

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        strFile, cstrFolder & strFile, True

        i = i + 1
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop
    MsgBox i & " Files are imported"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: yes and I have put my original code above!!!! I now need help tweeking it.  thanks for  your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced your code, "Do While Len(strFile) > 0" into "Do While Int(Mid(strFile, 7)) < 48", hope it helps.

```
Sub Sample2()
Const cstrFolder As String = "F:\TCB_HR_KPI\Data View\"
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Long

strFile = Dir(cstrFolder & "*.xls")
If Len(strFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Files Found"
Else
    Do While Int(Mid(strFile, 7)) < 48
        Debug.Print cstrFolder & strFile

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        strFile, cstrFolder & strFile, True

        i = i + 1
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop
    MsgBox i & " Files are imported"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:
Dir$()
DoWhile Val(Mid(filename, 7, 2))<48
   Import the file
   Dir$()
Loop