# DIR function and Naming Tables in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the DIR function to import a set of excel files into access.  I then pass the attributes of the DIR to make the name of the table in access the same as the excel file.  The only problem is that I also get xls in the name how I can I stop this?

Code below:

```
Sub Sample2()
Const cstrFolder As String = "F:\TCB_HR_KPI\Data View\"
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Long

strFile = Dir(cstrFolder & "*.xls")
If Len(strFile) = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Files Found"
Else
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Debug.Print cstrFolder & strFile

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    strFile, cstrFolder & strFile, True

    i = i + 1
    strFile = Dir()
Loop
MsgBox i & " Files are imported"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this ?

```
Sub Sample2() 
'
  Const cstrFolder As String = "F:\TCB_HR_KPI\Data View\"
'
  Dim i As Long, lng As Long
'
  Dim strExt As String, strFile As String, strTable As String
'
  strExt = ".xls"
  lng = Len(strExt)
  strFile = Dir(cstrFolder & "*" & strExt)
'
  If Len(strFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Files Found"
  Else
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      '
      ' Debug.Print cstrFolder & strFile
      '
      strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - lng)
      '
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        strTable, cstrFolder & strFile, True

      i = i + 1
      strFile = Dir()
    Loop
    MsgBox i & " Files are imported"
  End If
'
End Sub
```

As this a file like Sample1.xls will be improrted as the table Sample1.

Answer (score 1):

Strip it off as necessary with a helper function...

```
Function StripFileExt(FileName As String) As String
  Dim Pos As Long
  Pos = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If (Pos > 0) And (Pos > InStrRev(FileName, "\")) Then
    StripFileExt = Left$(FileName, Pos - 1)
  Else
    StripFileExt = FileName
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Split Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-function-HA001228911.aspx) to split on ".", and take the first element of that array for your table name.

```vb
Split(strFile, ".")(0)
```

You could store that result in a intermediate variable.  Or just use the expression directly in the `TransferSpreadsheet` statement.

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    Split(strFile, ".")(0), cstrFolder & strFile, True
```

**Note**: Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19813132/77335), I assumed the workbook file names contain only a single dot: names from *REPORT1.xls* thru *REPORT67.xls*  However if the file names you're dealing with this time can include more than one dot, my first suggestion is inappropriate.

In that case, you can still use an expression which includes `Split()`, but that expression would not be as simple.

```vb
Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - Len(Split(strFile, ".")(1)) -1)
```

Notice that approach would accommodate any of the other Excel file extensions in addition to *.xls*

Comment: Bad idea IMO, as the '.' character could in principle be part of the main file name (e.g., 'Report 10.10.13.xls' - your method would return 'Report 10' not 'Report 10.10.13').

Comment: To posterity - my previous comment was written before the edit. Can't say I'm personally keen on using Split just to find a final delimeter, but each to their own...