# Using Wildcards to access partial file names in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the

```
Public Sub ImportXLSS(fileName As String, tableName As String)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, True
End Sub
```

command in Access. When I call it with the full fileName, it works just fine. However, when I use a partial file name with an asterisk, It brings up a runtime error 3011. Do wildcards work differently in Access than Excel?

The first one works, but the second one doesn't

```
 ImportXLSS "C:\...\IDD Active WL 8-12-2020 TEST.xlsx", "DD Active"
 ImportXLSS "C:\...\IDD Active*", "DD Active"
```

Comment: Read [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet) docs. You must use a full file path. Asterisks are not supported and is unclear. If needing to import multiple files, loop over files.

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know. I'm not super familiar with vba.

Comment: This is not quite a VBA question but familiarity with an Access method. In fact, with COM-connected languages you can call this very method in Java, C#, Python, PHP, or R (outside of VBA). Be sure to read docs. Now, [Dir()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) that supports wildcards, `*` and `?`, is solely a VBA method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Excel files into Access whilst Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813132/import-excel-files-into-access-whilst-looping)